# xml parsing error (app is crashing)

Tags: android

my app is getting data from the server as xml response and it is working fine and showing reasonable data. But sometimes it is crashing and logcat showing xml parsing error.

but when we start app again it is working fine. but in future it might be showing xml parsing error.

thanks in adv..

Comment: which parser you are using?have u handled null checking?

Comment: plz post ur code or details about which parser u r using

Comment: Post the LogCat error as well

Comment: Perhaps caused by a corrupt or incomplete transfer?

Comment: Can you post your parsing code as well! Only then will we be able to help ya!